# How to select a list item present under UL in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

below is the code and i want to select the first list item i,e VAN.

```
<Div class="btn-group col-xs-12 noSidePad">
<button id="equipment-dropdown-btn" class="btn strip-radius btn-default dropdown-toggle col-xs-10 noSidePad" data-bind="html: selectedEquipment(), css: {'has-error' : $parent.errorMessage() && selectedEquipment() == 'Select...'}" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Flatbed</button>
<button class="btn btn-default equipt-toggle dropdown-toggle col-xs-2 noSidePad" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
<span class="caret"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul id="equipmentType" class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: equipmentTypeResults" role="menu">
<li>
<a data-bind="text: EquipmentName, click: $.proxy($parent.populateEquipment, $parent), attr: { 'data-itemtype': ResultType.toLowerCase(), 'data-equipid': EquipmentTypeId }" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" data-itemtype="parent" data-equipid="6">**Van**</a>
```

I am stuck , that should i first identify the drop down field and then select the list.

Any help or lead on this question is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First try with below Xpath

```
//ul[@id='equipmentType']/li/a[contains(.,'**Van**')]
```

If there is a dropdown which having this value then Yes you need to click on that dropdown first

```
driver.findElement(YOUR Locator)).click();
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='equipmentType']/li"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
  if("**Van**".equals(option.getText()))
    option.click();
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will be required to first click on the drop down button which you can get by Xpath to display(or toggle) the select list

`driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//button[//span[text()='Toggle Dropdown']]")).click();`

and then

`driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//ul[@id='equipmentType']//[text()='**Van*']")).click();`

you can use other values in place of `**Van**` to make it more generic